# django, datetime and timezones

Tags: python, django

I am using: datetime.now() to get the current time in an Event app that lets you create an event that has an end date, then all of the events are displayed in a calendar and if an event is passed due it is displayed in red.

My issue is that I have some users in different timezones than me saying that the events are ending at the wrong time.  They should end at midnight on the day they are due.

I have the timezone setup in my django settings.py.  When I use: datetime.now() is that going off of the users local timezone or is it going off of what timezone I have setup in django?

What I want is to find midnight for the users current timezone, so if my method above is wrong, how do I go about doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need your users to specify their timezone in their user profile. This can then be used to calculate local times correctly.

Check out [Relativity of time – shortcomings in Python datetime, and workaround](http://opensourcehacker.com/2008/06/30/relativity-of-time-shortcomings-in-python-datetime-and-workaround/) for some good information (and concrete examples).

**UPDATE:** From Django 1.4 it comes up with [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/timezones/) support. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the UTC Datetime instead then make the necessary adjustments based on the user's timezone:

```
import datetime

def getUtcNow():
    return datetime.datetime(*time.gmtime()[:6])
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a library to work with user timezones transparently. You should just use a Field and some timezone utils and you should get everything converted to the user timezone everytime you do a request or a query.

The library is named [django-timezones](https://github.com/FernandoEscher/django-timezones), and is a modification of the one that [Brosner first made](https://github.com/brosner/django-timezones).

Give it a try to see if it works for you.